# How to make a text box value in javascript readonly and incremental after button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I have a read only text box, i want to increase the value of that text box every time  the button is clicked. ex- value of text box is TC_001, i want to make it TC_002 after the button click...please provide me code..t

Answer (score 0):

basically, the textbox should be disabled:

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```

you can access it's value and increase it just like enabled input.
you can apply styles to disabled inputs as well so it won't be visible that it's disabled.

Answer (score 0):

you can set through javascript function, and call the funciton on `click` event of button.

```
var obj = document.getElementById("field-id");
obj.value = "changed value";
```